# Go code to list files in a Linux directory using getdents()

Tags: c, linux, go, system-calls

As an exercise, I wanted to translate some C code that used many syscalls into Golang. I found this [nice code example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120078/2372) on Unix & Linux StackExchange:

```
/*
 * List directories using getdents() because ls, find and Python libraries
 * use readdir() which is slower (but uses getdents() underneath.
 *
 * Compile with 
 * ]$ gcc  getdents.c -o getdents
 */
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dirent.h>     /* Defines DT_* constants */
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

#define handle_error(msg) \
       do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)

struct linux_dirent {
   long           d_ino;
   off_t          d_off;
   unsigned short d_reclen;
   char           d_name[];
};

#define BUF_SIZE 1024*1024*5

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int fd, nread;
   char buf[BUF_SIZE];
   struct linux_dirent *d;
   int bpos;
   char d_type;

   fd = open(argc > 1 ? argv[1] : ".", O_RDONLY | O_DIRECTORY);
   if (fd == -1)
       handle_error("open");

   for ( ; ; ) {
       nread = syscall(SYS_getdents, fd, buf, BUF_SIZE);
       if (nread == -1)
           handle_error("getdents");

       if (nread == 0)
           break;

       for (bpos = 0; bpos < nread;) {
           d = (struct linux_dirent *) (buf + bpos);
           d_type = *(buf + bpos + d->d_reclen - 1);
           if( d->d_ino != 0 && d_type == DT_REG ) {
              printf("%s\n", (char *)d->d_name );
           }
           bpos += d->d_reclen;
       }
   }

   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I have only been able to code this using `ioutil.ReadDir` which defeats the purpose. Does anyone have an idea on how to translate this?

Comment: is there a concrete problem you're trying to solve? If you want to go lower level than ioutil, use os.File.Readdirnames (which uses getdents at the lowest level from the syscall package). Check the `os` package source for hints (start with file_unix.go and dir_unix.go).

Comment: I was stuck with buffer management. `dir_unix.go` helps a lot! thanks +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid using this code. As written, it's wrong: on 32-bit systems and maybe even some 64-bit ones, `SYS_getdents` is the legacy syscall that doesn't provide `d_type` and lacks support for 64-bit inode numbers, which means you get gratuitous errors on modern filesystems. Even if you fix it, it's no better than inlining `readdir`, which does basically exactly the same thing internally.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I think "you shouldn't be doing this, and your question is based on a false premise that you should" is a reasonable answer to such a question as long as the answer provides some explanation as to why this is the case.

Comment: I don't think that's bad advice, but my thought was that this answer was too short for the question that was asked.  From the FAQ: 'The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”.'  I think that's useful in a situation where the person asking (and future people searching, too?) clearly states they are new to the language so the detail you provided might not be enough to be useful to them at this point on the experience curve.

Comment: The "try this instead" is obviously just using `readlink` or whatever equivalent Go provides. I agree that my answer probably isn't the best, most detailed possible version of this answer, but I don't think it's inappropriate as an answer either.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to do that but it doesn't seem to be efficient. Addressing that in a [followup question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25063756/in-go-why-does-file-readdirnames-make-a-clock-gettime-system-call)

Comment: The "most efficient" Go version (`os.File.Readdir()`) has the problem that it forces a `stat(2)` syscall for every file. In many cases, this is not necessary as the `d_type` field of the `dirent` struct could provide enough information. This is why a short, concise `find` clone in Go would be slower than find. If one cares to copy the Go stdlib code and make it work without the stat's, it's about as fast.