# In Go, why does "File.Readdirnames" make a "clock_gettime" system call?

Tags: linux, file, go, operating-system

As a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25022486/go-code-to-list-files-in-a-linux-directory-using-getdents), I am trying to write a Go program that only lists a files name in an efficient matter without unnecessary system calls. This is what I have thus far:

```
package main

import (
        "os"
        "fmt"
        "log"
)

func main() {

        // Open directory and check for errors
        f, err := os.Open(".")
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }

        // Get file names
        files, err := f.Readdirnames(0)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }

        // Print files
        fmt.Print(files, "\n")
}
```

However, when I run an `strace`, I see many of the following:

```
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1406822401, 824793686}) = 0
```

What does that pertain to? How can I make this code more efficient?

Comment: why do you think calls to `clock_gettime` are making your code inefficient?

Comment: I am doing `time` comparisons against the C code I posted in the previous question. The Go executable is significantly slower. Trying to figure out how to make them more comparable and this `clock_gettime` call happens frequently.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on my system with `go version devel +6acc2dd545b2 Thu Jul 31 12:55:40 2014 +0400 linux/amd64`

Comment: Are you comparing `time go run` or `go build && time ./exec`?

Comment: On x86_64, `clock_gettime` goes through the vdso so it happens entirely in userspace, costs basically nothing, and does not show up in strace. On 32-bit x86, kernels 3.15 and up support vdso `clock_gettime`, but glibc does not yet support it. Support should be in 2.21. musl libc already has support for it. No idea if the Go runtime has support yet.

Comment: Note that my comment isn't an answer to OP's question, just a thought on why @FUZxxl might be unable to reproduce the issue on 64-bit.

Comment: @R.. Can confirm, issue is reproducable on linux/386.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am spitballing, but I would think that it is related to Go's built-in scheduler and garbage collection.

Short answer is, go will never be quite as fast as C because it provides all of that extra runtime functionality which C doesn't.

The code you listed is probably the fastest way to do what you want in Go.

Answer (score -2):

clock_gettime is just a system call,which is called in go's runtime. runtime do a lot of things, schedual,  and so on, so it's normal for so many clock_gettime.

I don't think you can make this program more efficient, 'cause it is just for so tiny function .You shouldn't mind it.